# Is there anyway to programmatically restart my VSCODE extension?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am currently working on an extension for VScode that works with the MacBook Touch Bar. The Touch Bar API works by a allowing you to predefine a button in the package.json file like below

```
        "commands": [
            {
                "command": "extension.jumpBack",
                "title": "okay",
                "icon": "Images/play_Normal@2x.png"
            },
            {
                "command": "extension.jBack",
                "title": "Hello"
                //extension replaces Hello with a different word
            }

        ],
        "menus": {
            "touchBar": [
                {
                    "command": "extension.jumpBack",
                    "group": "Controls"
                },
                {
                    "command": "extension.jBack",
                    "group": "Controls",
                    "when": "!enabled"
                }
            ]
        }
```

These commands will cause VSCODE to display 2 buttons. One play button and the word 'Hello'. I took this to mean that there would be no way to update the words displayed after the extension begins running. My current implementation involves the extension writing a different word to the package.json, so when I restart the extension it will display the new word on the Touch Bar. I was wondering if there was any way for me to program a way to restart my extension so that the changes appear without completely closing Visual Studio Code.

Also any other suggestions on how to do this in a simpler fashion would be appreciated. Thanks stack

Comment: I think the best you could do is invoking the "reload window" command - that doesn't close the window, but it still effectively restarts all of VSCode / all extensions.

Comment: Thanks Garrett! Will try

Comment: ...Garrett!? :D

Comment: Not even sure you could classify that as dislexia. I just totally missed on that one.